# Dependencies problems in downloading and installing packages in Ubuntu 12.04LTS and held broken packages

Tags: dependencies, package, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-13.10, installation-package

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. I have installed 12.04 LTS in my laptop and it was moreover all fine. I want to install packages like wine,VLC,Chromium Browser,etc I was getting various error messages,such as ,

Error 1.Package Dependencies cannot be resolved.

While Installing Chromium from Ubuntu Software Center,

```
chromium-browser: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed Depends: libudev0 (>= 147) but 175-0ubuntu9.5 is to be installed Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.2.99.901) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.3-2build1 is to be installed Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1~precise1 is to be installed Depends: libxss1 but it is not going to be installed Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

While Installing VLC,

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.12ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.12ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

While installing Cheese Camera Booth also ,

```
cheese: Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: cheese-common (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1) but 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
```

Error 2.Unable to correct problems , you have held broken Packages.

I need solution to install the applications and packages and also to fixing this all.

I have tried for,

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean

then

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Error 3: `Unable to fetch some archives, may run apt-get update or try with --missing?`

This error also shows while running and executing `sudo apt-get update`
but of no use.
Please help me out .. or should I go for removing or changing Ubuntu Version to other if so please mention.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you

First a downgrade is required and done with the following: create the 'preferences' file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/preferences
```

and insert the following lines:

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=precise*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

Pin-Priority must be greater than 1000.

Then you may downgrade the offending applications with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Then you may install packages that complained about dependencies, like
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch, or sudo apt-get install ia32-libs.
```

Finally, you should remove the file you just created:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences
```

Now Install your prefer package

Answer (score -1):

Thanks!! The problem is solved .. !!

Nothing to go much more over coding.

Just change the server from India to US (`mirror.us.kernel.org`).Problem Solved ..Now upgrade it and install the package as per to you choice.